# Get path of temp uploaded file with image extension in PHP

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload

I have a form which lets the user upload the image file.

```
<div id="imageDiv">
             Image Path : <input class="imageOption" type="file" id= "uploadImageFile" name="uploadImageFile"  >
             </div>
```

The problem comes when I try to fetch the path from temp folder. I won't be needing the image files after processing the request. When I try to fetch the path with something like this

```
$imagePath =  $_FILES['uploadImageFile']['tmp_name'];
```

The path looks like **C:\wamp\tmp\phpA123.tmp.**
The API I'm using would require a path with extension of an uploaded image like this
**C:\wamp\tmp\image.png**

Couldn't figure out a way to do so unless I want to copy this image to some other upload folder and use it. I don't want these images logged in a server

Thanks

Answer (score 20):

It would be helpful to know the specific API in use, but no well written file storage API should ever have to rely on the uploaded file name being used to store a file.  You should be able to use the temp file contents in the API, and specify the file name separately.

In L5:

```
// Get the UploadedFile object
$file = Request::file('uploadImageFile');

// You can store this but should validate it to avoid conflicts
$original_name = $file->getClientOriginalName();

// This would be used for the payload
$file_path = $file->getPathName();

// Example S3 API upload
$s3client->putObject([
    'Key' => $original_name, // This will overwrite any other files with same name
    'SourceFile' => $file_path,
    'Bucket' => 'bucket_name'
]);
```

Comment: Thanks, I get your point to split and get things together later. The API I'm using is not for file storage, but for sending images/videos to clients. `$w->sendMessageImage($destination, $imagePath)` is one the method and I need path to that file ($imagePath) taken from form. I was looking for rather a better solution than getting name of file `$fileName = Input::file('uploadImageFile')->getClientOriginalName();` and storing it to the folder and getting the path `$imagePath = Input::file('uploadImageFile')->move($destinationPath, $fileName);`

Comment: Thanks dude, working fine.         $result = $s3->putObject(array(
            'Bucket'     => 'safezone-s3-bucket',
            'Key'        => 'test.jpg',
            'SourceFile' => $image->getPathname()
        )); . But instead of photo showing in the browser, it forces me to download it. how to fix it?

Comment: You might need to set your headers before returning the contents `$response->header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg');`

Comment: This helps to me. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

If you want to get same output as -

`$imagePath =  $_FILES['uploadImageFile']['tmp_name'];`

in Laravel, you can do something like this as described by @cdbconcepts -

`$file = Request::file('uploadImageFile');
 $imagePath = $file->getPathName()`

Comment: `$file = Request::file('uploadImageFile'); `may give you error then you should use `$file = Input::file('uploadImageFile');`

Comment: Yes I agree with you @AshwaniPanwar